# asp.net-mvc get a dictionary in post action or how to transform FormCollection into a dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, formcollection

anybody knows how to transform the `FormCollection` into a `IDictionary` or how to get a `IDictionary` in the post action ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is just an equivalent of Omnu's code, but it seems more elegant to me:

```
Dictionary<string, string> form = formCollection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => formCollection[v]);
```

Comment: I think it's a matter of style, i personally think Omu's code is a little more verbose, but it's easier to see what happens.

Comment: prefer this solution, much neater

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:

```
            var form = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
            {
                var value = formCollection[key];
                form.Add(key, value);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

On .Net Core this one worked for me.

```
var collection = Request.Form.Keys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => Request.Form[v].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static IDictionary<string, string[]> GetFormParameters(FormCollection collection)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string[]> formParameters = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
        {
            if (key == null) continue;
            var value = collection.GetValues(key);

            // value = CrossSiteAttackUtil.CleanHtml(value);
            if (value != null)
            {
                formParameters.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
```