# MVC passing post parameter to a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC application that returns a `ResultObjekt` after processing a `FormulaData` object. That's a rest API called via HTTP-Post

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetResult")]
public ResultObjekt GetResult([FromBody]FormularData values)
{

}
```

Question: Is there a way to read all properties from `values` into a `Dictionary<string, string>` or a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` ?

e.g.

```
public class FormularData
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

should result into a `Dictionary<string,string>()` or a  `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

with values `{ {"Item1","Value1"}, {"Item2","Value2"}}`

My previous solution worked with `Querystring` and `HttpGet` instead of `HttpPost` and since I changed, `Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)` doesn't work anymore.

---

Here is my current - not so pretty solution:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetResult")]
public ResultObjekt GetResult([FromBody]FormularData values)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(values.Item1))
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Item1", values.Item1));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(values.Item2))
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Item2", values.Item2));
    }
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> result = list.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: Could you not just define the `values` param as `IDictionary<string, object>`, unless you need it bound to your FormularData class?

Comment: @Toshi, `ResultObjekt GetResult([FromBody]Dictionary<string, object> values)` Should also work

Comment: @Corporalis can't I use both? the FormularData class and the Dictionary?

Comment: @Toshi model binding does not work like that. it's one or the other. either keep your model and then use reflection to build dictionary or use the dictionary as the model.

Comment: @Toshi, show an example of how you intend on passing the model.

Comment: @Nkosi ok understood but in case of `QueryString` I can still access the original string data. Isn't there a way to access the post parameters?

Comment: @Toshi, because query string is by standard a collection of key/value pairs. body could be anything.

Comment: @Nkosi if i decide to use `Dictionary<string, object>` is there a way to make this object to a `FormularData` object? Or do I have to write a own mapping method?

Comment: If you require both a dictionary and a `FormulaData` object, you will need to specify one as a parameter and then map it in your action. Do you actually need both and if so why? (considering refactoring) I'm assuming the controller action you've provided is simplified just to show the mapping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764837/asp-net-mvc-get-a-dictionary-in-post-action-or-how-to-transform-formcollection-i
may be this is helpful to you

Answer (score 10):

As already mentioned by many in the comments that ideally one should use a model that can hold the values from the form. This is also the cleanest way as per my opinion, as I find it more structured.

If you need to access both at the same time, first try to refactor/restructure the code if possible. In my opinion why try to access the raw form data when that is already bound to our model, considering the form data is a subset of the model data.

If refactoring/restructuring is not possible, and you need to access both, then there are couple of ways to do that.

1. Option1: Use [`FormCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.118).aspx):

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ResultObjekt GetResult(FormCollection formCol, FormularData model)
   {
       //Note that here both FormCollection and FormularData are used.
       //To get values from FormCollection use something like below:
       var item1 = formCol.Get("Item1");
   }
   ```
2. Option2: Use [`Request.Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.form(v=vs.110).aspx):

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ResultObjekt GetResult(FormularData model)
   {
       //To get values from Form use something like below:
       var formData = Request.Form;
       var item1 = formData.Get("Item1");
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

**Update:** As also pointed out by [Lali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937460/mvc-passing-post-parameter-to-a-dictionary/41996847#comment71170423_41937460), whether you use `FormCollection` or `Request.Form`, you can convert that into dictionary as: `formData.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => formData[v])` (untested), as both are of type `NameValueCollection`

Answer (score 4):

While using reflection may have a performance hit you can convert the model to a dictionary using linq with reflection.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetResult")]
public ResultObjekt GetResult([FromBody]FormularData values)
{
    var result = values.GetType()
                     .GetProperties()
                     .ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, pi => (string)pi.GetValue(values));
}
```

performance can be improved by caching the property info returned from `GetProperties`. The above linq can also be converted to an extension method for reuse if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making your life difficult for no reason.
If you need to treat your class as a dictionary just implement an implicit operator like in the following example

If you just want to iterate on the object,you can just implement IEnumerable

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FormularData data = new FormularData() { Item1 = "aa", Item2 = "bb" };
            //Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = data;
            foreach (var item in data)
                Console.WriteLine(item);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class FormularData : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
    {
        public string Item1 { get; set; }
        public string Item2 { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator Dictionary<string, string>(FormularData obj)
        {
            var list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Item1))
                list.Add("Item1", obj.Item1);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Item2))
                list.Add("Item2", obj.Item2);
            return list;
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((Dictionary<string, string>)this).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The power of Extension methods can be used out here.

1. Define an extension for FormularData class:

   ```
            public static class FormularDataExtensions
            {
               public static Dictionary<string, string> ConvertToDictionary(this FormularData formularData)
               {
                 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formularData.Item1))
                     dictionary.Add(nameof(formularData.Item1), formularData.Item1);
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formularData.Item2))
                     dictionary.Add(nameof(formularData.Item2), formularData.Item2);

                return dictionary;
               }
            }
   ```
2. Call ConvertToDictionary() in GetResult() as:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ActionName("GetResult")]
   public ResultObjekt GetResult([FromBody]FormularData values)
   {
       var dictionary = values.ConvertToDictionary();
   }
   ```